# SharePoint List Connected to PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a PowerApps canvas app that I created and within that app, it connects to a SharePoint list.  But when I click on New or Edit in the SharePoint list, it still uses the out of the box SharePoint form.  I see an "Integrate with PowerApps" option on my SharePoint list, but I already built the PowerApps form and don't want to recreate.  How can I have the New and Edit command connect to that PowerApps form?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can import already created Power Apps Forms (even connected to a list) into a SharePoint list. SPO Custom forms are embedded in the list/library itself.

For more info on this consult, MS Document (Q&A) [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)

1. Create Custom List/Library Forms by using the link in the menu bar as shown below
   [image]
2. And then update "Form Settings" of the list/library

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, **Canvas Power Apps** cannot be integrated with the SharePoint list as a custom form.

**Canvas Power App:**

**Pros:**

- Design for Desktop, Mobile, or both using Responsive configuration
- Full screen display mode
- Native mobile integration using Power App phone app

**Cons:**

- Unable to use SharePoint Integration object (list actions) to interact with form
- Forced to open form in new tab

**SharePoint list form Power App**

**Pros:**

- Use SharePoint Integration object (list actions) to interact with form
- Open form in ‘Panel’ mode without leaving page

**Cons:**

- No full screen mode
- Awkward interface for mobile device

If you want to customize forms, you can do it through the SharePoint list form Power App.

[image]